# Dropzone.js upload using php does not follow through

Tags: php, sql, dropzone

I have a PHP and SQL code that uses Dropzone.js to try and upload photos and add to the database. My issue is that i get a error when I try to use the dropzone for a picture.

**Heres my Dropzone div:**

```
        <div class="col-md-4 bg-color-white shadow border-radius"><!-- Photos { -->
          <div class="row bg-color-dark-gold border-top-radius">
            <div class="col-md-12 color-white section-title-bar">
              <span class="ion-image"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; PHOTO
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="for_lease_sale_photos_upload.php?i=<?php echo($rowProduct['productid']); ?>" class="dropzone"></form>
            <br>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>
        </div>
```

**UI:**

[image: upload photo]

If I try to drag a photo, my other codes do not follow through and get this error message:

[image: error]

```
[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace 
(`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. m 
Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like 
element attribute values in order to load these resources. See 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.
```

I am confused why I get the error of "whitespace" and less-than characters because I do not seem to have those.

This is my page URL:

```
http://localhost/infinitygroup/cms/for_lease_photos_list.php?i=1
```

the i=1 is from my SQL statement

I was also told to check the "Network" tab in the developer tools to see if I can find the error there.There seems to be no less than or white space in any file.

[image: Network]

As seen in the screenshot, my photo is being blocked.

Will appreciate any help in solving my error. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the url that is being blocked, it does not match what you say the url is posting to. 
You say it is supposed to post to

```
    for_lease_photos_list.php?i=1
```

but just by looking at the url in the console screenshot you can see that there are other urlencoded characters present.
We can see

```
    for_lease_photos_list.php?i=%3Cbr%20/%
```

which decodes to

```
    for_lease_photos_list.php?i=<br /%
```

Make sure that

```
    $rowProduct['productid']
```

does actually contain a valid integer and not some other characters as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="/css/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<form class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

Initialize dropzone in js

```
    <script>
    var counter=1;
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
      maxFilesize: 25,
        url: '/tset/index.php',
        init: function() {
          this.on("addedfile", function(file) { console.log('UPLOADED');});
          this.on("success", function(file,response) {
            file.additionalInfo = response;
            });
        },
        error: function(file, message) {
          $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-error").find('.dz-error-message').text('Something went wrong!');
        },
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        removedfile: function(file) {
            var dir = "./path/images/";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/call/removefile",
                type: "post",
                data: {name: file.additionalInfo, dir: dir},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            file.previewElement.remove();
            return false;
        }

   };
  </script>
```

Comment: check in firefox or some other browser except chrome